# How to optimize this select

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

```
SELECT *
FROM   trips,
       dates
WHERE  places_number_on_flag > 0
       AND places_number > 0
       AND ( places_number - ( (SELECT Count(id)
                                FROM   resrv_customers
                                WHERE  trip = trips.id
                                       AND ow > 0)
                               + (SELECT Count(id)
                                  FROM   resrv_customers
                                  WHERE  trip = trips.id
                                         AND extra_seat = 1
                                         AND ow > 0) ) < 20 )
       AND dates.id = trips.trip_date
       AND dates.from_date > 2458553;
```

It returns 5 rows after about a minute and 50 seconds.

I want it to be faster.

Comment: Have you had a look at the execution plan?

Comment: Please post the relevant `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements plus the plan. You should also rework the query using explicit join syntax for better readability.

Comment: @dodekja . . . You should explain what logic the query is implementing.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

One optimization would be to only run the sub-query once and use conditional aggregation to count the seats:

```
SELECT *
FROM   trips
  JOIN dates on dates.id = trips.trip_date
WHERE  places_number_on_flag > 0
       AND places_number > 0
       AND ( places_number - ( (SELECT Count(id) + count(id) filter (where extra_seat = 1)
                                FROM   resrv_customers
                                WHERE  trip = trips.id
                                       AND ow > 0)) < 20 )
       AND dates.from_date > 2458553;
```

Note that I replaced your ancient and fragile implicit joins in the WHERE clause with an explicit `JOIN` operator. It does not have any impact on performance, it's just better coding style.

Comment: I would add: use variable names instead of "*". And remember, Explain Analyse will help you know the cost of every step.

Answer (score 0):

We can try rewriting your query using a join to the `resrv_customers` table, instead of using costly correlated subqueries:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        trip,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ow > 0 THEN 1 END) AS cnt1,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extra_seat = 1 AND ow > 0 THEN 1 END) AS cnt2
    FROM resrv_customers
    GROUP BY trip
)

SELECT *
FROM trips t
INNER JOIN dates d
    ON t.trip_date = d.id
LEFT JOIN cte r
    ON r.trip = t.id
WHERE
    places_number > 0 AND
    places_number - (r.cnt1 + r.cnt2) < 20 AND
    d.from_date > 2458553;
```

Indexing here could be tricky, because you are doing a `SELECT *`.  To get Postgres to use any index, you might have to do a lot of column covering, i.e. creating large indices.

Comment: Just a comment on optimisation, that CTE will actually likely bottleneck the process since it will need to group and count up the whole `resrv_customers` table, when you only need to match the `trip.id`. Also `ow > 0` could be in the where clause since both counts require it, plus using the `filter` clause (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) is generally faster than a `case` inside of a count.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with rc_count as
(
    select trip, count(*) as ow_count, sum( (extra_seat = 1)::int ) as ow_count_with_extra_seat
    from resrv_customers
    where ow > 0
    group by trip    
)

SELECT *
FROM   trips
join   dates on dates.id = trips.trip_date
join   rc_count rc on trips.id = trip 
WHERE  places_number_on_flag > 0
       AND places_number > 0
       AND dates.from_date > 2458553
       and places_number - (ow_count + ow_count_with_extra_seat) < 20
```

Comment: Note: This answer is almost identical to what I posted earlier.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Didn't notice that. I focused on writing my own answer, and I also moved the shared condition `ow > 0` to where clause